# Getting CSS issue with html submit button

Tags: html, css, button

I have created CSS button from this site [cssportal.com](http://www.cssportal.com/css3-button-generator/) but after adding to my site I am getting different from original created. Why I am getting border from left and top.

Original View:

[image]

but currently I am getting this:

[image]

My Fiddle: [Sample](http://goo.gl/zEvu9K)

Comment: Which browser are you trying it in?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xm73g/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a `border: 0;` to the CSS...

**Preview**

Normal and Hover versions:

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xm73g/3/

```
.wpcf7-submit {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #3498DB;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0;
    background: #3498DB;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #3498DB, #3498DB);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498DB, #3498DB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3498DB), to(#3498DB));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498DB, #3498DB);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the remove the original browser border:
http://jsfiddle.net/xm73g/2/

(`border: 0px;`)

Answer (score 1):

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xm73g/1/)

Its basic style for button, because button acts like your cursor is pressing it and again it came back to original position.

Please add `border:none;` to your button style.

Answer (score 0):

Put also border:0 to the button  and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Add border:none; in the css code like this:

```
.wpcf7-submit {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border:none;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #3498DB;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #3498DB;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #3498DB, #3498DB);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498DB, #3498DB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3498DB), to(#3498DB));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498DB, #3498DB);
}
.wpcf7-submit:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border:none;
    background: #468CCF;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #468CCF, #63B8EE);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #468CCF, #63B8EE);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#468CCF), to(#63B8EE));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #468CCF, #63B8EE);
}
```